# Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

This is really hard to explain and I have no clue why I am getting a 'database' error.

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) error
```

when I click to my link here after I start the server and started the postgresql server

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/bookmarks
```

I have sphinx installed. I configured sphinx properly. Its deployed on heroku properly.
I am using postgresql for sphinx not mysql. I have the mysql2 gem which is required for me to use sphinx with postgresql

Here is my database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pinny_development
  pool: 5
  username: judyngai
  password:
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pinny_test
  pool: 5
  username: judyngai
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pinny_production
  pool: 5
  username: judyngai
  password:
  host: localhost
```

I am quite new to rails. It was working properly until I added jquery, d3, and boostrap to my app/assets folders and linked to them using javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_include_tag on my applications.html.erb

Here is a part of my applications.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap.min.css" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "d3.v3.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.min.js" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Earlier I deployed this on heroku and got a precompiled assets error so according to stackover I set

```
config.assets.compile = true  in production
```

Here is my heroku logs

http://pastebin.com/SDZqZu7x

Can someone give me the answer/answers?

Comment: Are you using postgresql or mysql?

Comment: This is a Sphinx connection error - as it's Sphinx that's using the mysql2 gem. What version of Thinking Sphinx are you using? And do you have the Flying Sphinx Heroku add-on enabled?